# How to connect a Node.js app to an http rest API from a docker service?

Tags: node.js, rest, docker, docker-compose, axios

A web-app in Node.js connects to an api with axios.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function fetchList() {
  return axios.get('https://api.website.dev/v1/posts')
}
```

The api works well, all is fine.

---

Now, I use `docker-compose` to run the exact same nodejs web app inside a container.

docker-compose.yml:

version: "3.1"

services:

```
  nodejs:
    image: node:alpine
    working_dir: /home/app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ../nodejs:/home/app
    command: ["npm", "start"]
```

The axios call to the Rest API returns an error:

```
error { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.domain.dev:443
  at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
  at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)
  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'api.domain.dev',
host: 'api.domain.dev',
port: 443,
config:
 { adapter
…
```

**How to make the nodejs app connect to the api from a docker container?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dns server inside docker cluster does not know anyting about host `api.website.dev`

You can explicetelly set Ip address of this host. Try to add `extra_hosts` to the service definition in `docker-compose.yml`

```
nodejs:
    image: node:alpine
    working_dir: /home/app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ../nodejs:/home/app
    command: ["npm", "start"]
    extra_hosts:
      - "api.website.dev:<IP_ADDRESS>
```

Or if you have external DNS server which knows something about `website.dev` you can add it to docker cluster as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dns)

Comment: Thank you. I tried that with `api.website.dev:127.0.0.1` (as the api. runs on localhost) but now it does an `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443`

Comment: it happens because 127.0.0.1 it is a localhost. nodejs try to connect to nodejs container, not to your host. Try to add `extra host` with another IP address of you host machine like `192.168.1.33`.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) may help you

Comment: It works, thank you so much! Still, it's weird because it removes the portability of a docker project. A specific IP has to be defined for local, test and prod environments. Is there a way to make that dynamic? (I'm going to read the other answer)

Comment: Also you can add network with driver `host` to `docker-compose.yml`. Then your docker network will be the same host network. I didnt try this before but it will work.

Comment: Do you have a link about the `host` driver?

Comment: Yes.first answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)